# How can I generate signal and record with NAudio at the same time?

Tags: c#, record, naudio

I want to make a sine signal, play it with speaker, receive it using MIC, and then record it.

I tried to make some programs to achieve that as below, but some problems occur.

Generate Sine Signal -> Speaker -> MIC -> Record (wave)

**1) WaveOut :**
 I used two WaveOut.

a) To Generate Signal

b) To Record a wave file.
 Does it make a problem?

**2) Echo Sound :**

**a) Earphone :**

If I use earphone, I can hear pure sine sweep sound. But MIC can't heard this sound. and then it will just record environment sound.

**b) Speaker :**

If I use speaker (same earphone line, I just add amplifier and speaker), I can hear echo sound as below picture. And MIC also record this echo sound.
  I can guess MIC received this sound and after some millisecond Speaker add this sound on Original sound. But I can't understand why Speaker add this received sound. How can I record without echo sound?

**3) Recording Time :**

I want to record 2 sec. Then I used timer and defined timer.Interval = 2 sec. 
  But real record time is over 2 sec. some delay?

**4) Sweep Time :**

I defined 2 sec sweep time. But during over 2 sec, sine sweep is not finished. At finish time (about 2.2 sec) frequency is 1.5kHz. (I defined End frequency 
 =2kHz).

[Recorded Echo Wave file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwG3u.jpg)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private WaveIn recorder;
    private BufferedWaveProvider bufferedWaveProvider;
    private SavingWaveProvider savingWaveProvider;
    private WaveOut player;

    private WaveOut player_sweep;   // 190305

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnStartRecording_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // set up the recorder
        recorder = new WaveIn();
        recorder.DataAvailable += RecorderOnDataAvailable;

        // set up our signal chain
        bufferedWaveProvider = new BufferedWaveProvider(recorder.WaveFormat);
        savingWaveProvider = new SavingWaveProvider(bufferedWaveProvider, "temp.wav");

        // set up playback
        player = new WaveOut();
        player.Init(savingWaveProvider);

        // 190305   / Signal Generator : Sine 50~2000 Hz, 2 sec
        SignalGenerator sweep_out = new SignalGenerator();
        sweep_out.Gain = 1;
        sweep_out.Frequency = 50;
        sweep_out.FrequencyEnd = 2000;
        sweep_out.SweepLengthSecs = 2;
        sweep_out.Type = SignalGeneratorType.Sweep;

        player_sweep = new WaveOut();   // 190305
        player_sweep.Init(sweep_out); // 190305

        // begin playback & record
        recorder.StartRecording();

        timer1.Enabled = true;

        // begin playback & record
        player.Play();      // Start Recording

        player_sweep.Play();    // 190305
    }

    private void RecorderOnDataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs waveInEventArgs)
    {
        bufferedWaveProvider.AddSamples(waveInEventArgs.Buffer, 0, waveInEventArgs.BytesRecorded);
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)    // 190305
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;

        player_sweep.Stop();    // 190305

        // stop playback
        player.Stop();

        // stop recording
        recorder.StopRecording();


        // finalise the WAV file
        savingWaveProvider.Dispose();

    }
}
```

Comment: Tagging for later. When I get home I'll share my solution

Answer (score 0):

I studied again NAudio. ( https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/audio-programming-naudio/ )
And I got the solution as below.

My Target : Generate Sine Signal -> Speaker -> MIC -> Record (wave)

using this, I want to analyze the speaker conditions additionally using FFT.

1. Generate Sine Signal :NAudio.Wave.SamplePrividers.SignalGenerator
2. Speaker Output :NAudio.Wave.WaveOut
3. Microphone : NAudio.Wave.WaveIn
4. Record(wave) : NAudio.Wave.WaveFileWriter

// Source Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.Diagnostics;   // for Process, Stopwatch
using NAudio.Wave;    // for WaveOut, WaveIn
using NAudio.Wave.SampleProviders;  // for SignalGenerator

namespace Speaker_Record-Wave
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // 0) StopWatch
        Stopwatch stopWatch;

        // 1) Signal Gen -> Speaker
        WaveOut waveOut;
        SignalGenerator signalGenerator;

        // 2) MIC -> Wave
        WaveIn waveIn;
        WaveFileWriter waveFileWriter;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void bt_Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // 0) StopWatch
            stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopWatch.Start();

            // 1) Signal Gen -> Speaker
            Start_Signal();

            // 3) Timer_Sweep
            timer_Sweep.Interval = 1500;
            timer_Sweep.Enabled = true;

            // 2) MIC -> Wave
            Start_Record();
        }

        private void timer_Sweep_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // 3) Timer_Sweep
            timer_Sweep.Enabled = false;

            // 1) Signal Gen -> Speaker
            waveOut.Stop();

            // 2) MIC -> Wave
            waveIn.StopRecording();

            // 4) 공통
            waveOut.Dispose();
            waveIn.Dispose();
            waveFileWriter.Dispose();

            // 0) StopWatch
            stopWatch.Stop();
            TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
            string es = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}:{3:00}",ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds / 10);

            tb_Result.AppendText(es + "\n");
        }

        private void bt_Open_Folder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process.Start(".\\");   // Open Folder
        }

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        // 1) Signal Gen -> Speaker
        private void Start_Signal()
        {
            signalGenerator = new SignalGenerator();
            signalGenerator.Type = SignalGeneratorType.Sweep;
            signalGenerator.Frequency = 50;
            signalGenerator.FrequencyEnd = 5000;
            signalGenerator.SweepLengthSecs = 1.5;

            waveOut = new WaveOut();
            waveOut.DeviceNumber = 0;
            waveOut.Init(signalGenerator);
            waveOut.Play();
        }

        // 2) MIC -> Wave
        private void Start_Record()
        {
            waveIn = new WaveIn();
            waveIn.DeviceNumber = 0;
            waveIn.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(44100, 16, 1);

            waveIn.DataAvailable += OnDataAvailable;
            waveIn.RecordingStopped += OnRecordingStopped;

            waveFileWriter = new WaveFileWriter("1_Recorded.wav", waveIn.WaveFormat);

            waveIn.StartRecording();
        }

        // 2) MIC -> Wave
        private void OnDataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
        {
            if (waveFileWriter != null)
            {
                waveFileWriter.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
            }
        }

        // 2) MIC -> Wave
        private void OnRecordingStopped(object sender, StoppedEventArgs e)
        {
            waveIn.Dispose();
            waveFileWriter.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```